# Average Based on Column Headers between certain numbers

Tags: excel, string, average, countif, sumifs

So this has been a challenging problem for me. I am trying to get Excel to do an average over a period of time based on what is in the column header.

So here's the column header that I'm talking about:

[image: where the result should go]

This is where the (Result) should go.

And then here is my original data (Nut Cost)

[image: original data]

So the intent is that I can take the average for Peanuts between 201604 and 201703 based on the header '201604-201703 Avg'.

My thought is to use something like this:

```
=averageifs('Nut Cost'!$B$2:$P$5,'Nut Cost'!$A$1:$P$1,left('Result'!B2,6):mid('Result'!B2,8,6),'Nut Cost'!$A$2:$A$5,'Result'!$A2)
```

My other thought is to use something like this:

```
=SUMIFS('Nut Cost'!$B$2:$P$5,'Nut Cost'!$A$1:$P$1,">="&LEFT('Result'!B2,6),'Nut Cost'!$A$1:$P$1,"<="&MID('Result'!B2,8,6),'Nut Cost'!$A$2:$A$5,'Result'!$A2)
```

which would be divided by a countif with similar style.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX to return the correct row to the AVERAGEIFS()

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX('Nut Cost'!$B$2:$P$5,MATCH('Result'!$A2,'Nut Cost'!$A$2:$A$5,0),0),'Nut Cost'!$B$1:$P$1,">=" & left('Result'!$B$1,6),'Nut Cost'!$B$1:$P$1,"<=" & mid('Result'!$B$1,8,6))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use this code translated to the actual workbook I'm using and it doesn't work. I get a #VALUE error. If I remove the 0 for the column_num in the index function I get a #REF error. I'm not sure what the problem is since when I evaluate the formula it seems to be resolving correctly until when it does the final calculation.

Comment: It works on the data you presented, as to why it does not work on your actual data, I can't begin to figure out as I do not have access to your data.

Comment: What is the actual formula you are trying?

Comment: =AVERAGEIFS(INDEX('PMPM By Class'!$B$4:$AX$24,MATCH('Class PMPM Analysis'!$A3,'PMPM By Class'!$B$4:$B$24,0),0),'PMPM By Class'!$C$4:$AX$4,">=" & LEFT('Class PMPM Analysis'!B$2,6),'PMPM By Class'!$C$4:$AX$4,"<=" & MID('Class PMPM Analysis'!B$2,8,6))

Comment: Change the first reference to `$C$4:$AX$24`  The number of columns needs to match those of the rest of the AVERAGEIFS()

Comment: I get a #DIV/0! error when I do that and the values are not 0

Comment: I got back around to doing this and your formula is correct. I had a data type issue with a couple of the column headers. Thank you for your help.